# Failed to run map query remotely.Failed to execute map query on the node

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I'm using SqlFieldsQuery in ignite 2.4 v.
It is working fine for sometime and after that giving exception:

```
Failed to run map query remotely.Failed to execute map query on the node: c7823704-201f-473f-9113-776d7d9a80d8, 
class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException:Failed to set schema for DB connection for thread
```

Here is my querying client's code:

```
Ignition.setClientMode(true);

        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("config/default-config_new_version.xml")) {

            try (IgniteCache<String, EntityFactDev> igniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("ENTITY_FACT_DEV")) {

                LOGGER.debug("done");

                QueryCursor<List<?>> queryCursor = igniteCache
                        .query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select count(*) from ENTITY_FACT_DEV.EntityFactDev"));

                System.out.println(queryCursor.getAll());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify the DB schema explicitly in cache configuration? 
If not, then you should use a quoted cache name as schema in the query. Like this:

```java
new SqlFieldsQuery("select count(*) from \"ENTITY_FACT_DEV\".EntityFactDev")
```

Comment: Hi Denis, still no luck.

Comment: @RajashekharMeesala, please provide your cache configuration. How do you configure the table? What exception do you get on the server node?